# Problem using the Arden's Lemma on one automata

Tags: automata, regular-expressions

I am trying to find the regular expression of this automata using the Arden's Lemma:

[image]

Let $L_{i}$ be the language accepted from the state $i$, this is what I got:

- $L_{1} = 1^{*}0L_{2}$
- $L_{2} = 1L_{1} + 0L_{3}$
- $L_{3} = \epsilon + 0^{*}1L_{2}$

As the first state is the initial one, I have to solve $L_{1}$. As $L_{1}$ is expressed using $L_{2}$, I have to first solve $L_{2}$.

$L_{2} = 1(1^{*}0L_{2})+0(\epsilon + 0^{*}1L_{2}) \\ L_{2}=11^{*}0L_{2} + 0\epsilon + 00^{*}1L_{2} \\ L_{2}=(11^{*}0+00^{*}1)L_{2} + 0$

Using Arden's Lemma, I get $L_{2}=(11^{*}0+00^{*}1)^{*}0$

Thus we have now:

$L_{1}=1^{*}0L_{2}=1^{*}0((11^{*}0+00^{*}1)^{*}0)$

Yet, based on this expression, the word "000" isn't accepted. Where is my issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The mistake is in the equation for $L_3$: it should be $0^*$ instead of $\epsilon$.

Comment: You mean it should be $0^{*} + 0^{*}1L_{2}$? Why doesn't $\epsilon$ fit there?

Comment: That's right. You figure out why $0^*$ should replace $\epsilon$.

Comment: Sorry for my last comment, I forgot to add the '$' symbole somewhere, and I am unable to edit it nor delete it. I was writing:
I know that $0^{0}=\epsilon$, So putting an epsilon becomes repetitive. I just don't seem to understand why would this ruin my regular expression for the whole automata?

Comment: The formula you state for $L_3$ is just wrong. According to your formula, $0 \notin L_3$, whereas clearly $0 \in L_3$. So your formula is wrong. Your "rule of thumb" is correct inasmuch $0^*$ includes $\epsilon$; but you should be using a rule of thumb but rather something more reliable, a formula that works in *all* cases, not just most cases (which is what rules of thumb are about). In mathematics our statements should cover absolutely all cases.

Comment: @JohnMayne You didn't ruin the whole regular expression, you just forbid the automaton to stop at any time except immediately after entering the state `III`. As soon as the first 0 transition is done it just has to do a finite number of them and then go to `II` without a second chance of escaping. Much like if it was $L_3 = \epsilon + 0L_4 + 1L_2$, $L_4 = 0^\ast1L_2$. So by using an $\epsilon$ instead of an $0^\ast$ you created another valid automaton which, exactly as you found, does not accept `000`. Disclaimer: not a CSientist.